# How to set JVM arguments in Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat7

In eclipse I put these arguments into the run configuration but now I want to upload my app to the server (tomcat 7) and I have always error in deployment. so I want to know how to set these variables in the server as i did in eclipse?

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution :D

I use tomcat7w.exe, in java tab, I add the arguments into Java options and it works.